# AWS Site to Site VPN Openswan Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, ipsec, libreswan

I am doing a pretty straightforward exercise by setting up an IPSec VPN with AWS.  I am using AWS Linux 2 Image and Openswan 3.25.

Error:
Failed to add connection "Tunnel1", esp="aes128-sha1;modp1024" is invalid: ESP encryption algorithm 'aes' is not supported.

Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

After fiddling with this for quite a bit, we found a solution to it, but I wouldn't consider it a permanent solution yet.

Change the /etc/ipsec.d/aws.conf with the following:

```
phase2alg=aes_gcm
ike=aes256-sha1;modp1024
```

I hope it helps.